# Ant Script for running Java file with class path

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I would like to simplify my life of running a Java file using a script. I think Ant script may work.

Each time I want to run my program (in Unix System), I have to write the following command

```
java -classpath ".:someclass" MyFile
```

Or if the user is using Windows:

```
java -classpath ".;someclass" MyFile
```

It is possible to create a script that will run the above commands (depending on the operating system, that is to understand what operating system is and to run the appropriate version of the command)?

Cheers

Comment: Why not create an [executable jar file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)? Then you can always use the same command `java -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: the point is to simplify my life during the development. Creating each time a jar I think I will waste allot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is three month old, but I think is worth sharing the code as may will be helpful for others.

In general the idea of running a class from a `.jar` file is useful and has many applications.

The most straightforward solution to your problem is the following code:

```
   <!-- Classpath of Your Jar file -->
   <path id="dist.classpath"> 
      <pathelement location="dist/MyFile.jar"/> 
   </path> 

   <target name="someclass"> 
      <java fork="true" classname="YourJarClassName"> 
          <classpath refid="dist.classpath"/> 
      </java> 
   </target>
```

You can now run:

```
ant someclass
```

And your `YourJarClassName` within the `jar` file will run.
So note that the target name `someclass` is the name you will use to run the `YourJarClassName` class.